# Getting a bad_alloc in the while loop

Tags: c++

I have a problem with incrementing cur value, after that i get an bad_alloc error. Can someone tell me why is that happening cause i don't really understand. The program below is saving into the vector every number as many times as the number's value, then printing content of the vector.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include "printSTL.h"
using namespace std;

int main(){

    vector<int> v;
    v.reserve(100);
    int cur = 1;
    while(v.size() != 100){
        for(int i = 0; i<cur; i++){
              v.push_back(cur);
        }
        cur++;
        
    }
    //this is just my function to print out the value of an stl container
    printSTL(v, " ", true);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `bad_alloc` means you're out of memory.

Comment: have you verified in a debugger that v .size() is ever == 100? A safer condition would be `v.size() < 100`.

Comment: @drRobertz i mean when i comment out the line: cur++; then it is working and printing out a vector of 100 ones, even if i use v.size()<100 same thing happens

Comment: Why do you reserve 100 if you want to store 5050 items?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while(v.size() != 100){
```

This will stop the loop when the vector's size is exactly 100.

Inside the loop you will first add 1 value to the vector. Next time two values. Then three, and so on.

If you work out the math on a piece of paper you will discover that you will never end up with exactly 100 values in the vector. The 13th iteration of the loop ends up with 91 values in the vector. The next iteration of the loop adds 14 more values, bringing the total to 105, and it keeps growing in perpetuity trying, in vain, to wind up with exactly 100 values in the vector.

The Golden Rule Of Computer Programming says: "your computer will do exactly what you tell it to do instead of what you want it to do". You told your computer to stop only when there are exactly 100 values in the vector, so that's what it'll try to do. Since you gave it a logically impossible task, it just keeps gobbling up memory until it runs out and crashes.